# Javascript filter array with multiple filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, filter, filtering

I trying to filter the data, wherein I have multiple filters. 
I have tried multiple techniques with map(), for but I am getting all the objects or none of them.

filtersSelected is the object where all my filters are placed.

status is data[i].status, amount is data[i].payment_detail.amount_charges.lc_amount

I was trying to filter the data depending upon user selection, filtersSelected is keys selected by the user in the front end. User can select the data in any order(Filter selected).

```js
var filtersSelected = {
  status: ['acknowledged', 'save_as_draft'],
  amount: [100000009],
  expiry: [],
};

var data = [{
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "3cade470-c0ba-11e9-9adc-795e8c9df56c",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "",
    "lc_id": "as3d24sfi",
    "initiation_date": "",
    "lc_type": "conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "FGBCONV",
      "issuer_reference": "GHQ ARMED Forces Direct of Fin Aff",
      "name": "G H Q"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Tafale Aero Systems"
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-08-31T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": true,
    "visited": true
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 100000009,
      "currency": "Dirhams"
    },
    "valid": true,
    "visited": true
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "Any Bank",
      "credit_available_by": ""
    },
    "valid": true,
    "visited": true
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "qwert",
      "shipment_to": "qwerty"
    },
    "valid": true,
    "visited": true
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": true,
    "visited": true
  },
  "attached_documents": [],
  "status": "acknowledged",
  "status_updated_at": 1566231731134,
  "updatedAt": "1566025738195",
  "createdAt": "1566024172600",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}, {
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "040887d0-bcf8-11e9-9ead-37268ca96a91",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "Gunther Systems_32",
    "lc_id": "1023LC2313",
    "initiation_date": "16-05-2019",
    "lc_type": "Conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "TC Gorsch_88",
      "issuer_reference": "Emirate of Abu Dhabi Finance Dept",
      "name": "GHQ"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Gunther Systems S.A."
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-05-09T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 800000,
      "currency": "EUR"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "UBDS Bank",
      "credit_available_by": "By Def Payment"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "Atlanta, USA",
      "shipment_to": "Abu Dhabi, UAE"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "attached_documents": [{
    "file_name": null,
    "file_path": null
  }],
  "status": "returned_to_ghq_for_correction",
  "status_updated_at": 1566231731134,
  "updatedAt": "1565970913070",
  "createdAt": "1565610901767",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}, {
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "fefc48b0-bce5-11e9-a1f1-93c532b8cd7a",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "South West Corp 007",
    "lc_id": "1023LC2312",
    "initiation_date": "21/12/2018",
    "lc_type": "Conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "TC Gorsch",
      "issuer_reference": "G H Q Directorate of FIN Affairs",
      "name": "GHQ"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Tafale Aero Systems"
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-05-09T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 9000000,
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "Any Bank",
      "credit_available_by": "By Def Payment"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "Atlanta, USA",
      "shipment_to": "Abu Dhabi, UAE"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "attached_documents": [],
  "status": "submitted_to_bank_for_authorization",
  "status_updated_at": 1566231731134,
  "updatedAt": "1565603162342",
  "createdAt": "1565603162342",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}, {
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "8686fe30-bce4-11e9-a1f1-93c532b8cd7a",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "South Corp_89",
    "lc_id": "1023LC2329",
    "initiation_date": "11/05/2016",
    "lc_type": "Conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "TC Gorsch_18",
      "issuer_reference": "G H Q Directorate of FIN Affairs",
      "name": "GHQ"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Marthsell Adv Tech Solutions"
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-05-09T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 4500000,
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "Any Bank",
      "credit_available_by": "By Def Payment"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "Atlanta, USA",
      "shipment_to": "Abu Dhabi, UAE"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "attached_documents": [],
  "status": "approaching_expiry",
  "status_updated_at": 1566231731134,
  "updatedAt": "1565602530750",
  "createdAt": "1565602530750",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}, {
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "1d154790-bce4-11e9-a1f1-93c532b8cd7a",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "North and South Corp_89",
    "lc_id": "1023LC2310",
    "initiation_date": "11/05/2016",
    "lc_type": "Conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "TC Gorsch_18",
      "issuer_reference": "G H Q Directorate of FIN Affairs",
      "name": "GHQ"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Hewlett Harbin First Mach"
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-05-09T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 4500000,
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "Any Bank",
      "credit_available_by": "By Def Payment"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "Atlanta, USA",
      "shipment_to": "Abu Dhabi, UAE"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "attached_documents": [],
  "status": "not_processed",
  "status_updated_at": 1566231731134,
  "updatedAt": "1565602353885",
  "createdAt": "1565602353885",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}, {
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "f5a59830-bcdf-11e9-9264-812f5d20a14a",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "North and South Corp_89",
    "lc_id": "1023LC2316",
    "initiation_date": "11/05/2016",
    "lc_type": "Conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "TC Gorsch_18",
      "issuer_reference": "G H Q Directorate of FIN Affairs",
      "name": "GHQ"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Hewlett Harbin First Mach"
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-08-20T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 4500000,
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "Any Bank",
      "credit_available_by": "By Def Payment"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "Atlanta, USA",
      "shipment_to": "Abu Dhabi, UAE"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "attached_documents": [],
  "status": "not_processed",
  "status_updated_at": 1566153000000,
  "updatedAt": "1565600569724",
  "createdAt": "1565600569724",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}];


function updateData(data) {


  // 'save_as_draft'

  const updatedDataArr = data.filter(item => {
    for (key in filtersSelected) {
      if (item.status === filtersSelected[key]) {
        return false;
      }
      //  arr = filtersSelected[key].map( selectedFilter => {
      // if(item.status ===  selectedFilter){
      //         return false;
      //       }
      //   })

      // filtersSelected = {
      //   status : ['save_as_draft'],
      //   amount: [],
      //   expiry:[],
      // };


      // }
    }
    return true;
  });
  console.log(updatedDataArr);

}
updateData(data)
```

Comment: Your data doesn't have `amount` or `expiry` fields. What are those filters supposed to do?

Comment: @ggorlen and Barmar .. Updated the question

Answer (score 3):

`filtersSelected[key]` is an array, not a string. You need to check if the value of the corresponding property is any of them, not compare the whole thing. You can use the [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method for this.

You're testing `item.status` against all the filters. You should test `item[key]` to test the property corresponding to the specific filter. However, the keys `amount` and `expiry` don't exist in your data, so I'm not sure what you intend them to do.

```js
function updateData(data) {
  // 'save_as_draft'

  const updatedDataArr = data.filter(item => {
    for (key in filtersSelected) {
      if (filtersSelected[key].some(f => item[key] == f)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  });
  console.log(updatedDataArr);

}

var filtersSelected = {
  status: ['acknowledged', 'save_as_draft'],
  amount: [100000009],
  expiry: [],
};

var data = [{
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "3cade470-c0ba-11e9-9adc-795e8c9df56c",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "",
    "lc_id": "as3d24sfi",
    "initiation_date": "",
    "lc_type": "conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "FGBCONV",
      "issuer_reference": "GHQ ARMED Forces Direct of Fin Aff",
      "name": "G H Q"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Tafale Aero Systems"
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-08-31T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": true,
    "visited": true
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 100000009,
      "currency": "Dirhams"
    },
    "valid": true,
    "visited": true
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "Any Bank",
      "credit_available_by": ""
    },
    "valid": true,
    "visited": true
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "qwert",
      "shipment_to": "qwerty"
    },
    "valid": true,
    "visited": true
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": true,
    "visited": true
  },
  "attached_documents": [],
  "status": "acknowledged",
  "status_updated_at": 1566231731134,
  "updatedAt": "1566025738195",
  "createdAt": "1566024172600",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}, {
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "040887d0-bcf8-11e9-9ead-37268ca96a91",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "Gunther Systems_32",
    "lc_id": "1023LC2313",
    "initiation_date": "16-05-2019",
    "lc_type": "Conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "TC Gorsch_88",
      "issuer_reference": "Emirate of Abu Dhabi Finance Dept",
      "name": "GHQ"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Gunther Systems S.A."
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-05-09T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 800000,
      "currency": "EUR"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "UBDS Bank",
      "credit_available_by": "By Def Payment"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "Atlanta, USA",
      "shipment_to": "Abu Dhabi, UAE"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "attached_documents": [{
    "file_name": null,
    "file_path": null
  }],
  "status": "returned_to_ghq_for_correction",
  "status_updated_at": 1566231731134,
  "updatedAt": "1565970913070",
  "createdAt": "1565610901767",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}, {
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "fefc48b0-bce5-11e9-a1f1-93c532b8cd7a",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "South West Corp 007",
    "lc_id": "1023LC2312",
    "initiation_date": "21/12/2018",
    "lc_type": "Conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "TC Gorsch",
      "issuer_reference": "G H Q Directorate of FIN Affairs",
      "name": "GHQ"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Tafale Aero Systems"
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-05-09T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 9000000,
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "Any Bank",
      "credit_available_by": "By Def Payment"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "Atlanta, USA",
      "shipment_to": "Abu Dhabi, UAE"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "attached_documents": [],
  "status": "submitted_to_bank_for_authorization",
  "status_updated_at": 1566231731134,
  "updatedAt": "1565603162342",
  "createdAt": "1565603162342",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}, {
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "8686fe30-bce4-11e9-a1f1-93c532b8cd7a",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "South Corp_89",
    "lc_id": "1023LC2329",
    "initiation_date": "11/05/2016",
    "lc_type": "Conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "TC Gorsch_18",
      "issuer_reference": "G H Q Directorate of FIN Affairs",
      "name": "GHQ"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Marthsell Adv Tech Solutions"
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-05-09T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 4500000,
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "Any Bank",
      "credit_available_by": "By Def Payment"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "Atlanta, USA",
      "shipment_to": "Abu Dhabi, UAE"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "attached_documents": [],
  "status": "approaching_expiry",
  "status_updated_at": 1566231731134,
  "updatedAt": "1565602530750",
  "createdAt": "1565602530750",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}, {
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "1d154790-bce4-11e9-a1f1-93c532b8cd7a",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "North and South Corp_89",
    "lc_id": "1023LC2310",
    "initiation_date": "11/05/2016",
    "lc_type": "Conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "TC Gorsch_18",
      "issuer_reference": "G H Q Directorate of FIN Affairs",
      "name": "GHQ"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Hewlett Harbin First Mach"
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-05-09T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 4500000,
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "Any Bank",
      "credit_available_by": "By Def Payment"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "Atlanta, USA",
      "shipment_to": "Abu Dhabi, UAE"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "attached_documents": [],
  "status": "not_processed",
  "status_updated_at": 1566231731134,
  "updatedAt": "1565602353885",
  "createdAt": "1565602353885",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}, {
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "f5a59830-bcdf-11e9-9264-812f5d20a14a",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "North and South Corp_89",
    "lc_id": "1023LC2316",
    "initiation_date": "11/05/2016",
    "lc_type": "Conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "TC Gorsch_18",
      "issuer_reference": "G H Q Directorate of FIN Affairs",
      "name": "GHQ"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Hewlett Harbin First Mach"
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-08-20T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 4500000,
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "Any Bank",
      "credit_available_by": "By Def Payment"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "Atlanta, USA",
      "shipment_to": "Abu Dhabi, UAE"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "attached_documents": [],
  "status": "not_processed",
  "status_updated_at": 1566153000000,
  "updatedAt": "1565600569724",
  "createdAt": "1565600569724",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}];

updateData(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) and [indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) method, you can filter your data and can store the data in the separate array according to the filter. You are using filtersSelected[key] which is an array, so you have to fetch the data as you fetch from an array. You can do something like this:

```js
var filtersSelected = {
  status: ['acknowledged', 'save_as_draft'],
  amount: [100000009],
  expiry: [],
};

var data = [{
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "3cade470-c0ba-11e9-9adc-795e8c9df56c",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "",
    "lc_id": "as3d24sfi",
    "initiation_date": "",
    "lc_type": "conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "FGBCONV",
      "issuer_reference": "GHQ ARMED Forces Direct of Fin Aff",
      "name": "G H Q"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Tafale Aero Systems"
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-08-31T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": true,
    "visited": true
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 100000009,
      "currency": "Dirhams"
    },
    "valid": true,
    "visited": true
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "Any Bank",
      "credit_available_by": ""
    },
    "valid": true,
    "visited": true
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "qwert",
      "shipment_to": "qwerty"
    },
    "valid": true,
    "visited": true
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": true,
    "visited": true
  },
  "attached_documents": [],
  "status": "acknowledged",
  "status_updated_at": 1566231731134,
  "updatedAt": "1566025738195",
  "createdAt": "1566024172600",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}, {
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "040887d0-bcf8-11e9-9ead-37268ca96a91",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "Gunther Systems_32",
    "lc_id": "1023LC2313",
    "initiation_date": "16-05-2019",
    "lc_type": "Conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "TC Gorsch_88",
      "issuer_reference": "Emirate of Abu Dhabi Finance Dept",
      "name": "GHQ"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Gunther Systems S.A."
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-05-09T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 800000,
      "currency": "EUR"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "UBDS Bank",
      "credit_available_by": "By Def Payment"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "Atlanta, USA",
      "shipment_to": "Abu Dhabi, UAE"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "attached_documents": [{
    "file_name": null,
    "file_path": null
  }],
  "status": "returned_to_ghq_for_correction",
  "status_updated_at": 1566231731134,
  "updatedAt": "1565970913070",
  "createdAt": "1565610901767",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}, {
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "fefc48b0-bce5-11e9-a1f1-93c532b8cd7a",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "South West Corp 007",
    "lc_id": "1023LC2312",
    "initiation_date": "21/12/2018",
    "lc_type": "Conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "TC Gorsch",
      "issuer_reference": "G H Q Directorate of FIN Affairs",
      "name": "GHQ"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Tafale Aero Systems"
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-05-09T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 9000000,
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "Any Bank",
      "credit_available_by": "By Def Payment"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "Atlanta, USA",
      "shipment_to": "Abu Dhabi, UAE"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "attached_documents": [],
  "status": "submitted_to_bank_for_authorization",
  "status_updated_at": 1566231731134,
  "updatedAt": "1565603162342",
  "createdAt": "1565603162342",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}, {
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "8686fe30-bce4-11e9-a1f1-93c532b8cd7a",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "South Corp_89",
    "lc_id": "1023LC2329",
    "initiation_date": "11/05/2016",
    "lc_type": "Conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "TC Gorsch_18",
      "issuer_reference": "G H Q Directorate of FIN Affairs",
      "name": "GHQ"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Marthsell Adv Tech Solutions"
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-05-09T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 4500000,
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "Any Bank",
      "credit_available_by": "By Def Payment"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "Atlanta, USA",
      "shipment_to": "Abu Dhabi, UAE"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "attached_documents": [],
  "status": "approaching_expiry",
  "status_updated_at": 1566231731134,
  "updatedAt": "1565602530750",
  "createdAt": "1565602530750",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}, {
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "1d154790-bce4-11e9-a1f1-93c532b8cd7a",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "North and South Corp_89",
    "lc_id": "1023LC2310",
    "initiation_date": "11/05/2016",
    "lc_type": "Conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "TC Gorsch_18",
      "issuer_reference": "G H Q Directorate of FIN Affairs",
      "name": "GHQ"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Hewlett Harbin First Mach"
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-05-09T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 4500000,
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "Any Bank",
      "credit_available_by": "By Def Payment"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "Atlanta, USA",
      "shipment_to": "Abu Dhabi, UAE"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "attached_documents": [],
  "status": "not_processed",
  "status_updated_at": 1566231731134,
  "updatedAt": "1565602353885",
  "createdAt": "1565602353885",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}, {
  "user_id": "admin",
  "uuid": "f5a59830-bcdf-11e9-9264-812f5d20a14a",
  "common_info": {
    "lc_name": "North and South Corp_89",
    "lc_id": "1023LC2316",
    "initiation_date": "11/05/2016",
    "lc_type": "Conventional"
  },
  "general_info": {
    "applicant_detail": {
      "bank_name": "TC Gorsch_18",
      "issuer_reference": "G H Q Directorate of FIN Affairs",
      "name": "GHQ"
    },
    "beneficiary_detail": {
      "name": "Hewlett Harbin First Mach"
    },
    "lc_detail": {
      "expiry_date": "2019-08-20T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "payment_detail": {
    "amount_charges": {
      "lc_amount": 4500000,
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "bank_other_party_detail": {
    "credit_available": {
      "type": "Any Bank",
      "credit_available_by": "By Def Payment"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "shipment_detail": {
    "general_info": {
      "shipment_from": "Atlanta, USA",
      "shipment_to": "Abu Dhabi, UAE"
    },
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "narrative_detail": {
    "valid": false,
    "visited": false
  },
  "attached_documents": [],
  "status": "not_processed",
  "status_updated_at": 1566153000000,
  "updatedAt": "1565600569724",
  "createdAt": "1565600569724",
  "valid": false,
  "visited": false
}];

let savedraft = [], ack = [], amt = [];
const updatedDataArr = data.filter(item => {
  let key = Object.keys(filtersSelected)
  for (key in filtersSelected) {
    if (key === 'status') {
      if (filtersSelected[key].indexOf(item.status) > -1) {
        if (item.status === 'save_as_draft') {
          savedraft.push(item.uuid)
        } else if (item.status === 'acknowledged') {
          ack.push(item.uuid)
        }
      }
    }else if (key === 'amount') {
      if (item.payment_detail.amount_charges.lc_amount===filtersSelected[key][0]) {
        amt.push(item.uuid);
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
});
console.log(savedraft);
console.log(ack);
console.log(amt);
```

**"status"** and **"amount"** in **"key === 'status'"** and **"key === 'amount'"** are the filters which you have kept in your data. I hope it helps.